# How can I inherit a template class in its specilization class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, derived-class

If I have a class like: `Vector<T>` (a template class), and now I want to specialize it: `Vector<int>`. How can I inherit from `Vector<T>`?

My code is:

```
template<typename T> class Vector&<int>:public Vector <T>
```

But it gives error:

> template parameters not deducible in partial specialization.

How should I deal with it?

I don't actually mean I want to use in Vector. But I want to understand what's wrong in langugae aspect?

Is that means specilization class can't inherit from other template classes?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Which specialization of `Vector` do you want `Vector<int>` to derive from? And more interestingly, *why* do you want to so derive?

Comment: What would inheriting from `Vector<T>` mean when `T` isn't specialized to a particular type, and the template for the subclass can't provide `T`? Where does the definition of `T` come from?

Comment: Please show a proper [mre]. What you are asking for doesn't seem to make sense. Why do you think you need to specialize `Vector<int>` specifically? Why do you think it should inherit from the template (or another specialization thereof)? My impression from the limited details is that you have a misunderstanding of what templates are and how they work.

Comment: What does this kind of a specialization mean to you? Can you explain, in short, brief, sentences: what, exactly, such a specialization is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: It feels like you're trying to perform specialization similar to what [`std::vector<bool>` involves](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), but that's not done with subclassing, it's done by defining the specialization of the templated class for that type directly.

Comment: It is not necessary to use HTML paragraphs here. The enter key works just fine. I've removed all of the unnecessary noise from your post and applied proper formatting so that it is readable. Please use the markdown help when posting your next question so that you can do it properly. Thanks.

Comment: I means if I have a template class, and if I specilization it , it only has the member I defined in it. But I also want some members in original classes? How should I realize it?     And more importantly, what's wrong my usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the specialised `Vector<int>` to inherit from the general `Vector<int>`. This is not possible as is, because there can be only one `Vector<int>`, but with a little trick you can do it. Just add another template parameter, a boolean non-type with a default value. Now for each `T`, there are two different `Vector<T, b>`, one for each possible `b`.

```
template <class T, bool = true> 
class Vector 
{ void whatever(); };
```

Regular users just use `Vector<float>` or `Vector<int>` without explicitly passing the second argument. But specialisations can pass `false` if they need to.

```
template<> 
class Vector<int, true> : public Vector<int, false> 
{ int additional_member; };
```